# How to subtract values from textbox in form from Field in table (Access '07 VBA)?

Tags: vba, ms-access, field, subtraction

I am developing a canteen transaction system in MS Access 2007. In my "Add Food Item:" form, I have a series of textboxes and comboboxes, a button, "Add Item" and a listbox. The names of text and combo boxes are as follows :

Textbox names:
txtRate,
txtQty

Combobox names:
cbxICode,
cbxItems

On the click of the Add Item button, the selected item with its quantity, rate etc. gets tranferred to the listbox. (I asked asked the transfer question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730416/add-values-to-a-multi-column-listbox-in-access-07-vba))

Now, in my tblItems, there is a "QtyAvailable" field which indicates the available quantity of the currently existing food items. How do I:

- Subtract the quantity of a food item the user enters from the QtyAvailable field in tblSampleData?

Advanced help is appreciated.

Thanks,

S Sandeep

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: The hyperlink is in the question, right? I had asked a certain Mr. Gord Thompson, a question for transferring the values from the combo to the list. If you could tell me your email id, I could directly send you the whole accdb.

Comment: chris.bain.cube@gmail.com :)

Comment: Just throwing this out there, it looks like you might want to use `DLookup()` http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a query def that performs the task on the table.  You can set up parameters in a query def by enclosing them in square brackets.  When MS Access does not recognize the name in the square brackets, it will prompt the user for a value.

Once that works correctly, search the NET for VBA examples on using ADO or DAO to get a copy of the query def in memory, set parameter value(s), and execute the query.  RECORDSET is for SELECT, EXECUTE is for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE

Answer (score 1):

The code below helped me:

```
Dim cdb as CurrentDb, rst As DAO.Recordset, qtySelected as Long
qtySelected = Me.txtQty.Value
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset ("tblItems", dbOpenDynaset)
With rst
.Edit
!QtyAvailable = rst!QtyAvailable - qtySelected
.Update
.Close
End With
```

For more details, visit the question I asked and see the latest of comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730416/add-values-to-a-multi-column-listbox-in-access-07-vba)